# Telegram Bot API Python | Отправка сообщений по таймеру

Tags: python, telegram

В прочем, не нашел то, как эту проблему можно решить не импортируя shedule модуль из pip. И вот, что я получил:

```
import time
import schedule

def send_message():
    bot.send_message(370921204, 'Hello')


schedule.every().day.at("02:14").do(send_message())
schedule.every().day.at("02:15").do(send_message())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Документация на модуль schedule - https://pypi.org/project/schedule/

При этом всем, вылетает ошибка на Heroku:
[image]
И помимо этого, сообщение отправляется только при запуске бота, игнорируя время и бот перестает работать, не воспринимает команды, текст и т.д.
Подскажите, как можно исправить это или предлагайте свои варианты реализации отправки по таймеру, а так же подскажите как совместить while True и то что внутри вместе с bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы опечаталась или невнимательно читали документацию. Замените в 8 и 9 строчках вашего примера `.do(send_message())` на `.do(send_message)`.

Comment: Исправил, но сообщение все равно не отправляется в заданное время, ошибки перестали вылетать

Answer (score 3):

1. В бесплатном варианте heroku - бот засыпает каждые 30 минут без получения запросов из вне. Чтобы будить его - используй [это](https://kaffeine.herokuapp.com).
2. В аргументах `bot.send_message` у тебя указан конкретный `chat id`. Если необходимо, что бы бот отвечал не только создателю, а любому своему пользователю - придется писать бота руками через [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/). Хотя и при текущей реализации, если ты хочешь добавлять команды через `@bot.message_handler` - то такой бот получится исключительно реактивным(реагирующим только на запросы пользователя). Тогда опять таки придется переехать на requests.
3. Что бы в данном виде работало без заморочек с пробуждением heroku - рекомендую создать [виртуальный сервер на Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/). Первый год, без превышения лимитов - это бесплатно.

Comment: Без каких либо запросов и пробуждений спокойно отправляет сообщения, единственное я промахнулся с часовыми поясами, но инфа полезная. А чтобы бот рассылал всем пользователям, я думаю сделать БД, где записываю ИД всех пользователей. Спасибо за ответ